# A 7-days suspension without warning

Tags: discussion, comments, account-suspension

Consider:

[image]

I got a 7-day suspension. Is it normal since the [music Stack Exchange site](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) policy is first: warn and then suspend?

Let me share the message from the mods:

[image]

To briefly sum up: I called a user's behaviour as 'toxic'. Since the user commented my answer referencing a question I asked yesterday and implying 'you say this and this, are really, really, really still don't get it?'.

I first called this behaviour as being toxic and asked the user to 'just point out the misinformation' for me to edit my answer.

When the user continued interrogating me (you will answer this, and this, and this and I'll give you plus points if you can...), I made a joke (something like 'I can't answer your questions, music theory is all about coin flipping.) and moved away.

The other issue in the message (the one about meta post) was weeks ago and I did not get a warning for that too.

My first question is:

1. **Is it all right to suspend without warning?**
2. **What should my expected (regarding the code of conduct) reaction have been** when a user simply took the answer out of context, interrogated me with several questions not directly related to the answer and commented by citing a question I asked before 'you asked this before, are you still, really, still, really don't understand?'? Flagging might be an option, but I did not flag it since it was not 'unfriendly'; it was threatening someone (me) as if I was a stupid idiot.

To prevent further problems, I need to understand this situation completely. **A warning would make sense since the word 'toxic' is yes, a problem. But I don't get the reason of a 7-day suspension without a warning.**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The screenshot is pretty clear; it's on a case-by-case basis and depending on the severity of the transgression, moderators could skip any of the prior steps. If your first post was spam for example, you could expect to go to account expulsion immediately without any warnings or suspension.

Your screenshot does say

> for most first time...

And the moderators have provided two examples, so you're starting to show a pattern of unwanted behaviour here. Just because your first post wasn't caught at the time is no defence.

We're not really in a position to view other site's deleted posts. If you have a complaint with the moderators on a particular site then you can use [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) - the link is on the screenshot too, otherwise when your suspension is over you can write a post on the [site meta](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/) although I wouldn't recommend it.

Having said that, calling other people names like toxic is not allowed by the [code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct). It specifically says

> No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language. Even if you don’t intend it, this can have a negative impact on others.

If in doubt, disengage, go answer some other question or do something else entirely. If you think any existing comments aren't useful then flag them.